# Is there a way to force Visual Studio 2008 (or below) to use a spellchecker for comments?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, comments, spell-checking

I'm not sure if this can be done at all, but it'd certainly make my life easier. I was wondering if maybe the MS spellchecker could be used as a plug-in for other applications... or something like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via [this free add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2007/12/13/spell-checker-for-html-asp-net-jscript-vb-c-css-and-c-for-visual-studio-2005-and-2008.aspx).

[Newer post](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/29/spell-checker-update-2-2-full-support-for-vs-2008-sp1-simpler-setup-and-a-few-bug-fixes.aspx)

Comment: Link to a newer version: http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/29/spell-checker-update-2-2-full-support-for-vs-2008-sp1-simpler-setup-and-a-few-bug-fixes.aspx  (note that for pre-VS2008 follow the links in the article for version 2.1)

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) from Whole Tomato comes with a Spell Checker, along with many other wondrous productivity enhancing features - if you're using Visual Studio without Visual Assist you're really missing out :)

Comment: Well I'm a proud owner of a R# license so I indeed know what I'm missing out: the spellchecker! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Visual Studio, but both Eclipse and Emacs have support for spellchecking inside comments. I usually have it off, because it too often gets in the way and complains about things like variable names, but then I don't really need a spellchecker (most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

You could use FXCop and write a custom rule to spellcheck ([link](http://davesbox.com/archive/2008/06/08/fxcop-now-ships-with-the-spell-checker-libraries.aspx)) your comments

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for automatically correcting typical typos everywhere you type:

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and the [AutoCorrect for English Script](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/OtherDownloads.htm)