# How would I edit keystrokes? VB2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to edit keystrokes, as when I type "--" I would like the program to edit the "--", wherever I entered it and turn it into an actual dash (—), how would I do so? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe defining your own snippet (like `cw` for `console.writeline`) may be easiest way (http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-visual-studio-code-snippets)

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't really coded in quite some time, I think this would be a bit too advanced for me at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Christophe said snippets are the way to go (and they are actually not THAT hard to define, as there is no "AutoCorrect" function as in MS Word ([How can I define instant AutoCorrect macros in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638045/how-can-i-define-instant-autocorrect-macros-in-visual-studio)).

Normal keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> can be modified via Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, but you cannot assign direct key combinations like your wanted "<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>" » "<kbd>—</kbd>"